# How to create multiple edmx in same project

Tags: entity-framework-6

i am new to EF ...
getting this error while adding another edmx in same project 
using same connection string .
this is my connection string

```
<add name="REFLECTIONDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER;initial catalog=REFLECTIONDB;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Sqlsa123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" />
```

Comment: this is my error :The EntityContainer name could not be determined. The provided EntitySet name must be qualified by the EntityContainer name, such as 'EntityContainerName.EntitySetName', or the DefaultContainerName property must be set for the ObjectContext.

Answer (score 0):

Same connection Strings Names are not allowed, you can have multiple Connection Strings but with separate names.

Change

`name="REFLECTIONDBEntities"`

To

`name="REFLECTIONDBEntities2"`